# "ExecutionException: : Cannot add a property to a sealed object." Except I don't... What is wrong?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I have received a strange email related to a project where I use Rhino (no Java 8 so I cannot use Nashorn). Original post [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/json-schema-validator/SpG2jk885B4/YcjSa2RFTgIJ). The guy receives a huge stacktrace and the relevant element (I think) is the last one which reads (reformatted a little):

```
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: 
        Cannot add a property to a sealed object.
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:61)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:549)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:587)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError0(Context.java:557)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.addSlot(ScriptableObject.java:1660)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getSlotToSet(ScriptableObject.java:1627)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:223)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdScriptable.put(IdScriptable.java:150)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.defineProperty(ScriptableObject.java:1036)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdScriptable.defineProperty(IdScriptable.java:233)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.defineProperty(ScriptableObject.java:1057)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdScriptable.addIdFunctionProperty(IdScriptable.java:451)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeString.fillConstructorProperties(NativeString.java:81)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdScriptable.addAsPrototype(IdScriptable.java:424)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeString.init(NativeString.java:60)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.initStandardObjects(Context.java:656)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.util.RhinoHelper.<clinit>(RhinoHelper.java:92)
    ... 72 more
```

`RhinoHelper.java:92` is mine. The relevant code snippet with the culprit line is this (`SCOPE` is a `Scriptable`; `REGEX_IS_VALID` and `REG_MATCH` are [rhino] `Function`s):

```
static {
    final Context ctx = Context.enter();
    try {
        SCOPE = ctx.initStandardObjects(null, true); // <-- FAILS HERE
        ctx.evaluateString(SCOPE, jsAsString, "re", 1, null);
        REGEX_IS_VALID = (Function) SCOPE.get("regexIsValid", SCOPE);
        REG_MATCH = (Function) SCOPE.get("regMatch", SCOPE);
    } finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

After some googling around, all the information I could gather is that this exception can occur when you seal the context (which I do) and try and redefine a function (or whatever is the name for JavaScript, I don't know the language) of the standard library. For instance, in [this link](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?57264-JavaScript-Cannot-add-a-property-to-a-sealed-object), the poster tries and redefines:

```
Date.LZ = function(x) {return(x<0||x>9?"":"0")+x};
```

And note that there is the *name* of the attempt override in the stacktrace. But I don't, and I don't believe I do anything of the sort. My only JavaScript "code" is this (I know, bad naming):

```
private static final String jsAsString
    = "function regexIsValid(re)"
    + '{'
    + "    try {"
    + "         new RegExp(re);"
    + "         return true;"
    + "    } catch (e) {"
    + "        return false;"
    + "    }"
    + '}'
    + ""
    + "function regMatch(re, input)"
    + '{'
    + "    return new RegExp(re).test(input);"
    + '}';
```

It is the first time I see this error. The guy also says that no other package than mine pulls in a Rhino dependency...

So, what is happening here? How can I circumvent this problem? Does it mean the context is already sealed somewhere else? But if the guy doesn't use Rhino "apart from me", how can this happen?

---

EDIT: workaround found by the user... He had a dependency on Weblogic which caused the bug.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I fixed the problem...

Rhino knowledge is really surprisingly scarce on the Internet but anyway, I fixed it in the most simple possible way:

```
-        SCOPE = ctx.initStandardObjects(null, true);
+        SCOPE = ctx.initStandardObjects(null, false);
```